# Background query to XAMPP server always returns null

Tags: java, php, android

For a project (a home security app), I've been trying get the status of some (for now, simulated) devices from a mySQL database running on a XAMPP server. I've been making an app on android studio with a menu with buttons for different services. One of the Buttons is to access the status of the different devices, which is as follows:

```
       {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View v) {
               UserHouseDetailsProcessing houseDetailsProcessing = new UserHouseDetailsProcessing(MainActivityUser.this);
               houseDetailsProcessing.execute("getHouseDetails");
               startActivity(new Intent(MainActivityUser.this, MyHouseActivity.class));

           }
       });
```

UserHouseDetailsProcessing is an Async task that queries the server, who's pertinent information looks like this:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.a49ersense.DTO.HouseDTO;

import org.apache.ivy.Main;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.ProtocolException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLEncoder;

public class UserHouseDetailsProcessing extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String> {

    Context context;
    SharedPreferences preferences;
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
    String tsk;
    UserHouseDetailsProcessing(Context ctx){this.context=ctx;}
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
        String task=strings[0];

        tsk=task;

        preferences=context.getSharedPreferences("MYPREFS",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        editor = preferences.edit();
        editor.putString("flag","0");
        editor.commit();
        String houseDetails="http://localhost/49ersense/getinfo.php";
        String updateGarage="http://192.168.43.21/49ersense/getinfo.php";
        String updateHouseStatus="http://192.168.43.21/49ersense/getinfo.php";
        String applianceDetails="http://192.168.43.21/49ersense/getinfo.php";

        try{

            if(task.equalsIgnoreCase("getHouseDetails")){
                URL url= new URL(houseDetails);
                HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection =(HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);

                //get info from database
                InputStream inputStream =httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
                InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8");
                BufferedReader bufferedReader= new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
                String dataresponse ="sdfg,asdf,asdf,asdf,asdf,as,df,asdf,asd,fa,sdf";
                String inputLine;
                Toast.makeText(context,dataresponse,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                while((inputLine=bufferedReader.readLine())!=null){
                    dataresponse+=inputLine;
                    Toast.makeText(context,dataresponse,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
                bufferedReader.close();
                inputStream.close();
                httpURLConnection.disconnect();
                Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivityUser.class);
                intent.putExtra("serverResponse",dataresponse);
                context.startActivity(intent);
                Toast.makeText(context,dataresponse,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                return (dataresponse);
            }
            if(task.equalsIgnoreCase("updateGarage")){
                URL url= new URL(updateGarage);
                HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection =(HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
                OutputStream outputStream= httpURLConnection.getOutputStream() ;
                OutputStreamWriter outputStreamWriter= new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8");
                BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(outputStreamWriter);

                bufferedWriter.flush();
                bufferedWriter.close();
                outputStream.close();

                //get info from database
                InputStream inputStream =httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
                InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8");
                BufferedReader bufferedReader= new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
                String dataresponse ="";
                String inputLine;



                while((inputLine=bufferedReader.readLine())!=null){
                    dataresponse+=inputLine;

                }
                bufferedReader.close();
                inputStream.close();
                httpURLConnection.disconnect();
                return (dataresponse);
            }if(task.equalsIgnoreCase("updateHouse")){
                URL url= new URL(updateHouseStatus);
                HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection =(HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
                OutputStream outputStream= httpURLConnection.getOutputStream() ;
                OutputStreamWriter outputStreamWriter= new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8");
                BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(outputStreamWriter);

                bufferedWriter.flush();
                bufferedWriter.close();
                outputStream.close();

                //get info from database
                InputStream inputStream =httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
                InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8");
                BufferedReader bufferedReader= new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
                String dataresponse ="";
                String inputLine;



                while((inputLine=bufferedReader.readLine())!=null){
                    dataresponse+=inputLine;

                }
                bufferedReader.close();
                inputStream.close();
                httpURLConnection.disconnect();
                return (dataresponse);
            }
            if(task.equalsIgnoreCase("getApplianceDetails")){
                URL url= new URL(applianceDetails);
                HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection =(HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
                OutputStream outputStream= httpURLConnection.getOutputStream() ;
                OutputStreamWriter outputStreamWriter= new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8");
                BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(outputStreamWriter);
                bufferedWriter.flush();
                bufferedWriter.close();
                outputStream.close();

                //get info from database
                InputStream inputStream =httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
                InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8");
                BufferedReader bufferedReader= new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
                String dataresponse ="";
                String inputLine;



                while((inputLine=bufferedReader.readLine())!=null){
                    dataresponse+=inputLine;

                }
                bufferedReader.close();
                inputStream.close();
                httpURLConnection.disconnect();
                return (dataresponse);
            }


        }catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            return "error ioexception: " + e.getMessage();
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            return "error ioexception: " + e.getMessage();
        } catch (ProtocolException e) {
            return "error ioexception: " + e.getMessage();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return "error ioexception: " + e.getMessage();
        }

        return "0";
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s){
        String[] serverResponse = s.split("[,]");
        if(tsk.equalsIgnoreCase("getHouseDetails")){
            if(serverResponse[0]!="0"){
                Intent intent = new Intent(context, MyHouseActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("serverResponse",s);
                Log.d("serverResponse",s);
                context.startActivity(intent);
            }else {
                Log.d("fetch database failed",serverResponse[0]);
            }
        }
        if(tsk.equalsIgnoreCase("updateGarage")){
            if(serverResponse[0]=="0"){
                Log.d("update garage failed",serverResponse[0]);
            }
        }
        if(tsk.equalsIgnoreCase("updateHouse")){
            if(serverResponse[0]=="0"){
                Log.d("update status failed",serverResponse[0]);
            }
        }
        if(tsk.equalsIgnoreCase("getApplianceDetails")){
            if(serverResponse[0]!="0"){
                Intent intent = new Intent(context, ManageAppliancesActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("serverResponse",s);
                context.startActivity(intent);
            }else {
                Log.d("fetch appliances failed",serverResponse[0]);
            }
        }

    }

}
```

The php code works when I run it manually on my XAMPP server, printing, in the form of a string precisely the values I want it to

Finally, myHouseActivity runs like this:

```
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my_house);
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        Bundle k = intent.getExtras();
        String s = k.getString("serverResponse");
//Other stuff
```

However, whenever I try running the pressing the button to, the app crashes on String s = k.getString("serverResponse");, as it is apparently the NULL object, which cannot be parsed. I've spent hours trying to solve this, but without any success.

The error is ass follows

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.a49ersense, PID: 8402
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.a49ersense/com.example.a49ersense.MyHouseActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.os.Bundle.getString(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3449)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.os.Bundle.getString(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.a49ersense.MyHouseActivity.onCreate(MyHouseActivity.java:38)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8000)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7984)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1309)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3422)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
```

The code should work, but the different functions don't seem to be communicating with each other. Have any of you encountered this problem?

Comment: Indeed. If you have `String s = k.getString("serverResponse")` Then somewhere you should have used .putExtra() on the intent to start your activity. I dont see you doing this in the first code block. Dont start your activity there as you do it in onPostExecute too. Which is ok.

Comment: `return "0";` You are doing nothing with the catch messages. In every catch block you should add someting like `return "error ioexception: " + e.getMessage();` And in onPostExcecute check if s starts with error. In that case display a Toast.

Comment: I have done everything that you have suggested, without success

Comment: I dont see you doing that and you did not even tell if there was a catch. Please update your code.

Comment: Have updated all the code

Comment: "error ioexception: " ou return four times the same exception where you also have a malformed and protocol and so. Further in onPostExecute you do not check if s starts with " error" .